# Convert datetime from substring T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion, substring

I have been trying to figure out how to convert a select result that returns 2 digits and then I want to convert it into year so then I can grab the max() value of that year.

My table:

```
ins_order
------------------------
RSN  |  ordered
---------------
1    |  A04-01
2    |  A12-02
3    |  A98-01
4    |  B00-10
2    |  B10-02
3    |  C97-01
4    |  C03-10
```

and so on...

My select state looks like this:

```
select 
    max(substring(orderid, patindex('%[0-9]-%', orderid) - 1, 2)) as year
from 
    ins.insorders
where 
    orderid is not null
group by 
    substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid))
order by 
    year
```

This will return:

```
year
---------
98           
10
97
```

but when I use max it returns the highest number for each letter, but before getting the highest number I need to convert this 2 numbers into year format so it can understand that 17 is actually the highest because we are in 2017.

Comment: By far the biggest issue here is that you violated 1NF by shoving multiple values into a single tuple like this. Now you are stuck fighting against a poor data structure. Given that you have 2 digit years you are going to have to make some decision about when to "switch" to 20 instead of 19. So you will isolate the two digit year and then add a case expression as your primary sort order. When YY < 50 then 1 else 0 end or something like that.

Comment: @SeanLange to be fair, we often do not get to design the structure of the data which we are querying. I would assume the OP wasn't the person who architected the data structure and simply has to find a solution because he can't just fix the format.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock of course. It doesn't change the fact that the challenge is fighting a poor architecture. It doesn't matter who actually designed it, the challenge is the same.

Comment: Well I been converting a huge application that was written for Oracle Database, so database is very old and I'm doing as much possible ways to not manipulate the existing data. I used the method that SqlZim posted and works great I just need to clean a little bit the database. Any way thank you for the information described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sean Lange said in his comment, you are going to have to convert your `substring()` to a meaningful value before trying to use it in a meaningful way.

```
select 
    Ltr = substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid))
  , Year = max(case when convert(int,substring(orderid, patindex('%[0-9]-%', orderid) - 1, 2)) < 50
  then convert(int,'20'+substring(orderid, patindex('%[0-9]-%', orderid) - 1, 2))
  else convert(int,'19'+substring(orderid, patindex('%[0-9]-%', orderid) - 1, 2))
  end)
from ins_orders
group by substring(orderid, 0, patindex('%[0-9]%', orderid))
order by year desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZRV37957

returns:

```
+-----+------+
| Ltr | Year |
+-----+------+
| A   | 2012 |
| B   | 2010 |
| C   | 2003 |
+-----+------+
```